# Can't switch to Windows from macOS

Tags: bootcamp

After upgrading to Monterey I can't switch to Windows from mac side. However, I can use the option key to select and start Windows as well as switch to macOS from Windows without an issue. My Windows is on NTFS and no chkdisk issue.

Comment: How do you want to switch from Windows to macOS?

Comment: you "can't switch to Windows from the Mac side." meaning what exactly? Selecting the Windows startup disk in System Settings/Preferences? Or what exactly?

Comment: @nohillside - I can switch to MacOS from Windows without any issue by using bootcamp menu. My issue is starting Windows.

Comment: @SteveChambers - Yes, selecting the Windows startup disk in MacOS system Settings/Preferences, it will still boot the MacOS.

Comment: You probably need to update the Boot Camp software from inside Windows - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/bcmpc69d1074/mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/456600/repair-mbr-or-gpt-table-from-recovery-as-both-oss-fail-to-boot), Windows 10 is installed to BIOS boot on your 2014 Mac.

The Mac Startup Manager exists in firmware and can be booted to by holding down the 'Option' key at startup. The Mac Startup Manager detects the existence of a BIOS booting operating system based on the values stored in the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table and the GUID Partition Table (GPT). This allows you to install a BIOS booting Linux, BIOS booting Windows or any other BIOS booting operating system.

Traditionally, the macOS operating system has looked at content of a volume in a partition flagged as BIOS bootable. If the correct files are found, then Windows will be presented as a possible the startup disk. ***Perhaps this has been removed from Monterey with respect to BIOS booting Windows 10 operating system installs.***

> One possible solution would be to use the Boot Camp Assistant to reinstall Windows 10. This would automatically install a UEFI booting Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to reinstall Windows 10.