# Repair MBR or GPT Table from recovery as both OSs fail to boot

Tags: macos, bootcamp, dual-boot

On my Mac Mini 2014 I tried to repair GPT table (MBR.. ?) with an answer given on [Trying to rebuild my partition map](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431237/trying-to-rebuild-my-partition-map) (using GPT fdisk, SIP disabled) for my issue of Windows 10 not booting itself but by going through the Option menu on each boot. And, it's messed up now.

I can't boot to any of the OS now. I even can't reinstall the MacOS. I have tried to take screenshots of the output with the reference of the thread. Please help me to recover my OSs.

[image: Disk Utility]

[image: Disk List]

[image: Show Disk]

[image: Mount Disk]

[image: fdisk]

HUM

[image: MacOS][image: Windows 10]

New screenshots:

1. DiskUtil
   [image: New DiskUtil]

Additional information:

```
Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$ ls /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/boot/bcd
ls: /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/boot/bcd: No such file or directory
Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$ sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
Volume EFI on disk0s1 mounted
Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$ ls /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bcd
ls: /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bcd: No such file or directory
Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$ diskutil unmount disk0s1
Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted

Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Password:
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60801/255/63 [976773168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 -   25 127  14 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF   25 127  15 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  195312496] HFS+        
*3: F7 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 195723264 -  781049856] <Unknown ID>
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
Hums-Mac-mini:~ humgurung$
```

UPDATE 2 RESULT:
[image: fdisk disk0]

Comment: What exactly did you boot to when you made the screenshots? Do you know which versions of macOS and Windows you have installed? Can you provide a screenshot of `fdisk /dev/disk0`?

Comment: I pressed Command+R key then the power button for recovery mode, then used Terminal. It's Monterey (100gb) and Windows 10 (400gb). Screenshots were added to the question above.

Comment: Why is there an image of a Windows PC? I don't quite get it

Comment: The Windows PC image is while trying to boot to bootcamp and elaborate on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer is only intended make macOS bootable. There may be further repairs which need to be made.

You should be able to use the following command to make macOS bootable.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0
```

This command is interactive. Enter the values in the order given in the first column of the table below.

| Entry | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `e 4` | command | Edit given table entry 4 |
| `0` | parameter | Partition id ('0' to disable) |
| `q` | command | Quit edit of current MBR, saving current changes |

---

Update 1:

If the Boot Camp Assistant is used to install Windows 10 on your 2014 Mac, Windows 10 is installed to UEFI boot. From what you have posted so far, it would appear Windows 10 is installed to BIOS boot. This could happen if you upgraded from a previous Windows install (such as Windows 7). The existence of a `BCD` file in the `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/boot` folder would indicate BIOS booting. In other words, the output from the command below can be used to help determined is Windows BIOS boots.

```
ls /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/boot/bcd
```

The existence of a `BCD` file in the `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft/Boot` folder would indicate UEFI booting. In other words, the output from the commands below can be used to help determined is Windows UEFI boots.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
ls /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bcd
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

Could you enter the above commands while booted to macOS and post the output?

---

Update 2:

The id the MBR table for the third partition should be `07`. This can be changed by entering the following command while booted to recovery mode.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0
```

The interactive entries can be taken from the first column of the table below.

| Entry | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `s 3` | command | Set the identifier of table entry 3 |
| `7` | parameter | Partition id |
| `q` | command | Quit edit of current MBR, saving current changes |
| `y` | parameter | (Optional) Enter if asked for OK |

> Note: In the MBR table, the id of the second partition currently is `AF`, which represents a HFS+ type partition. Actually, your second partition is APFS, but since there is no official id assigned to APFS, you might as well leave the id as `AF`.

Comment: Thank you, David. It is much appreciated. It worked like a charm. I can boot to MacOS now. I would be grateful if you could send me the instructions on further repairs to be made.

Comment: Post the current output for `diskutil list` and `fdisk /dev/disk0`.

Comment: 1. diskutil list - screenshot added to the question above as I can't post in the comment here.
2. fdisk result:
fdisk: /dev/disk0: Permission denied

Comment: I assumed you would be entering the `fdisk /dev/disk0` command from recovery, as you did when you first posted the output. You might be able to from macOS, but you would need to use `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and have disabled SIP.

Comment: 1. I entered the 'fdisk /dev/disk0' from macOS
2. Yes, the bootcamp was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10
3. Additional/updated output is added to the original quesion

Comment: Thank you again, David. After the Update 2 command, I can access Windows 10 by pressing 'Option' key while booting, otherwise, it boots to macOS even if I target restart 'Bootcamp'. fdisk command screenshot is posted above.

Comment: Furthermore, I had an additional partition within Windows 10 with Drive letter E: and it's missing now.

Comment: After pressing 'Option' key while booting, you have to hold down the 'Control' key when targeting restart 'Bootcamp' in order to make Boot Camp the default.

Comment: According to the values in the partition tables, there is no space for an additional drive E:. Perhaps the some of the values are wrong. Is the BOOTCAMP volume suppose to be 400 GB in size?

Comment: Yes, the BOOTCAMP volume is 400 GB in the size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144319/discussion-between-hum-gurung-and-david-anderson).